# Average length of consecutive numbers which have an increasing number of divisors

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the nine consecutive natural numbers starting from $1584614377$.

```
n = 1584614377 no. of divisors: 2
n = 1584614378 no. of divisors: 4
n = 1584614379 no. of divisors: 8
n = 1584614380 no. of divisors: 12
n = 1584614381 no. of divisors: 14
n = 1584614382 no. of divisors: 16
n = 1584614383 no. of divisors: 32
n = 1584614384 no. of divisors: 40
n = 1584614385 no. of divisors: 48
```

Their number of divisors is strictly increasing. This is an examples of a increasing sequence of the number of divisors of length $9$. For every positive integer $n \ge 1$, we calculate far we can go before the sequence of increasing divisors breaks. For some $n$ the sequence will break immediately at $n+1$ while for others it might go longer. The longest such sequence I have found so far is the above sequence of length $9$.

On an average how far we can go before the sequence breaks? Let $I_n$ be the average of length of increasing sequence for the first $n$ natural numbers.

**Update 12-12-21**:  Experimental data shows that $I_{10^6} \approx 1.537$ and $I_{1.2 \times 10^{10}} \approx 1.5537$. It will be nice if it converges to well known constant such as $\pi/2$.

**Question 1**: What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_n$?

Instead of an increasing sequence of divisors, let is consider a decreasing sequence of divisors and let $D_n$, be the average of length of decreasing sequence for the first $n$ natural numbers.

**Question 2**: Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}D_n$?

**Update 20-Jan-22**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414280/average-length-of-consecutive-integers-which-have-an-increasing-number-of-diviso) since it is unanswered in MSE.

Comment: See [OEIS sequrence A075028](https://oeis.org/A075028).

Comment: I think the most natural conjecture is that $I_n$ and $D_n$ tend to $e-1$. The function $\log \tau(k)$ (where $\tau(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$) is an additive function that asymptotically acts like a normal variable with mean and variance $\log2\cdot\log\log k$. Consecutive values of the function have correlations that are roughly bounded (being even/odd affects the number of divisors but only by a bounded factor, for instance); these correlations should vanish asymptotically, leaving us with a purely random model of indepedent samples from the same continuous distribution.